# How to wrap text in grid view

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am making a library management software.

I have the following xaml:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.Books, Mode=OneWay}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Book">

                <StackPanel Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

                    <Image Width="200" Height="200" Source="{x:Bind Path=CoverImageLocation, Mode=OneWay}" /> 

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Path=Title, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                       TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind Path=Author, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                       Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{x:Bind Path=Quantity, Mode=OneWay}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

The text in the text block is acquired from a database. Implementation details are not required I feel. The text blocks represent the title, author and quantity of the book respectively.

I have a book named: 'The subtle art of not giving a f*ck'. As you might have noticed, TextWrapping is set to WrapWholeWords. But this is the screenshot of the app:
[image: screenshot]

There are two things to note:

1. The text is not wrapped
2. Quantity is missing

How do I specify that the text block be wrapped? Or if that is not possible at least show ellipses at the end of long texts so that Quantity is not compromised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use Grid Instead of StackPanel to get proper text trimming with **TextTrimming** property.

   ```
   <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Book">
       <StackPanel Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
           <Image Width="200" Height="200" Source="{x:Bind Path=CoverImageLocation, Mode=OneWay}" /> 
           <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <ColumnDefinition />
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <StackPanel>
                   <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Path=Title, Mode=OneWay}" 
                             TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                   <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind Path=Author, Mode=OneWay}" 
                              Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
               </StackPanel>
               <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{x:Bind Path=Quantity, Mode=OneWay}"
                          Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
           </Grid>
       </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

Comment: TextTrimming works exactly as I want. Just remove the TextWrap property in the first TextBlock. Otherwise it doesn't work